# how to break a recursive callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here i passed a callback function which can call itself during runtime and prints a value incremented by one each time it gets called.I want it to break after a certain value.How i can do that?

i am getting the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

```
<html>
<body>
   <script>
       function main(callback) {
           callback(3);
       }

       main(function(val) {
           console.log(val);
           val > 50 ?    return false: return true;
           arguments.callee(val + 1);
       });
   </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will the function `arguments.callee(val+1)` ever be called? You are returning from the parent function in the previous line.

Comment: It is good manners to select an answer that was most helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can't `return` within ternary operator. Even if it can, your recursion won't work because it will always return before `arguments.callee` is executed. Also, it's not recommended to use `arguments.callee` since it will throw an error in strict mode.

```js
function main(callback) {
  callback(3);
}
main(function redo(val) {
  console.log(val);
  if (val > 50) return;
  redo(val + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning no matter what.

Instead, you need to continue with the recursive call if the termination condition is not met. Something like:

```js
function main(callback) {
  callback(3);
}

main(function(val) {
  console.log(val);

  // if condition is met, quit
  if (val > 50) {
    return;
  }
  
  // else do recursive call
  arguments.callee(val + 1);
  
});
```

You can also do this, if you want to keep the ternary operator:

`val > 50? false : arguments.callee(val + 1);`

Comment: thanks ,but what if i do something like this  val>50?return:arguments.callee(val+1);   not working either

Comment: In that case, you can use `val > 50? false : arguments.callee(val + 1);`  - the `return` clause does not play well with the ternary operator in this case

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this

`main(function(val) {
           console.log(val);
         if(  val < 50 )
           arguments.callee(val + 1);
       });`

And coming to the problem and the error

`val > 50 ?    return false: return true;`

This line of code is wrong, the ternary operator must be used to assign a value to variable and not use it like a executable block.

`var flag = val > 50 ?  false: true;`

Is valid.

Comment: No it will stop as soon as the value is 50

Comment: Lol. Yes I fixed it before reading the comments, And even then it wouldn't have been a infinite loop because my condition 3 > 50 would have failed in the first try and my loop would hv stopped

Comment: true, deleted my comments